# Adding item to collection from within a style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a style which targets DataGrids within a Grid.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

I would like to add an EventTrigger (using the [Microsoft XAML Behaviors library for WPF](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf)) within the style.

```
<b:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateSelection}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
</b:EventTrigger>
```

However, this:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="b:Interaction.Triggers">
            <Setter.Value>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateSelection}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
                </b:EventTrigger>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

fails, with a **XamlParseException**:

> 'Set property 'System.Windows.Setter.Property' threw an exception.' Line number '28' and line position '22'.
>
> Inner Exception 1:
>   ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: property

Although the reported exception seems to be unrelated, I assume this is because I am trying to set the `Interaction.Triggers` attached collection property with a single `EventTrigger`, instead of adding the `EventTrigger` to the collection.

**How can I add an item to a collection within a style in XAML?**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an interaction trigger in a `Style`. It's not supported.

What you can do instead is to define an attached behaviour that hooks up the event handler:

```
public class SelectionChangedBehavior
{
    public static ICommand GetCommand(DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        return (ICommand)dataGrid.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCommand(DataGrid dataGrid, ICommand value)
    {
        dataGrid.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static object GetCommandParameter(DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        return dataGrid.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCommandParameter(DataGrid dataGrid, object value)
    {
        dataGrid.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(SelectionChangedBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnCommandChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CommandParameter",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(SelectionChangedBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = d as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid != null)
            dataGrid.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        ICommand command = GetCommand(dataGrid);
        if (command != null)
            command.Execute(GetCommandParameter(dataGrid));
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="local:SelectionChangedBehavior.Command" Value="{Binding UpdateSelection}" />
    <Setter Property="local:SelectionChangedBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
</Style>
```

`WpfApp1` refers to the namespace of the `SelectionChangedBehavior` class in the above example.

Comment: @Zev Spitz: Did you try this?